# Can someone give a comprehensive guide on how to run NIST SP 800 90B entropy assessment c code in windows?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, entropy, nist

I am trying to run the github code in windows 11. I don't know what all I need to install in my laptop to run the C++ code. It would be a great help if someone can point out the steps to run the code.

Comment: Hello & welcome :-)  Which one?  IID or non-IID. Hint non-IID doesn't work. See http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/photonic/technical/90b_latest/